# C++11 return type deduction using auto and decltype

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, decltype

I am trying to write a function which multiplies a vector with a scalar value. 
I want to return a Vector with the type of the highest data type.

When I compile the below code I get the error as 
"error: argument to decltype must be an expression"

How do I fix this?

```
template<typename T>
class Vector {
private:
    T* data;
    int length;

    template <typename S>
    auto operator*(S scalar) const /
    -> decltype(Vector<typename std::common_type<S,T>::type>);
    {
        // Function Logic
    }
}
```

Comment: just drop the `decltype`. `Vector<typename std::common_type<S,T>::type>` is already the type that you want, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decltype` is for determining the type of an expression. `Vector<typename std::common_type<S, T>::type>` is *already* a type. So there's nothing to use `decltype` on.

Also, this is not return type deduction. It's merely a late-specified return type, which is unnecessary in this case, since the return type doesn't depend on any of the parameter names. You could just as easily do this:

```
template<typename S>
Vector<typename std::common_type<S,T>::type operator*(S scalar) const
```